How do I get the "make" command to work on the terminal of VScode?
Whenever I type "make" then the name of the program I get a message saying make isn't recognized as a cmdlet or function and that I should check if my path is correct
I've tried including mingw as a path and I expected it to have "make" as part of the functions in the terminal but the problem is still there

What is your %PATH%? Where is make actually installed (i.e. where is the actual program-file make or make.exe)?

make is not part of VS Code, so has to be installed separately.

How do I install make then?

Can't use command make for makefile on Visual Studio Code

Did you check whether you have make somewhere on your hard disk?

This question is similar to: Can't use command make for makefile on Visual Studio Code. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Installing make
Depending on the platform you use, installation of make can be different. Based on the platforms Visual Code Studio can be installed on, I've narrowed it down to three platform. In your question, you mentioned MinGW, a sort of GNU for windows, so I assume you are on Windows. If this is true, you can find installation on Windows under the first header labelled 'On Windows' below.
On Windows
First, if you're using Windows, especially for coding, at least try Linux (it's so much better). But no pressure, if Windows is better for you, that is not a problem.
Windows is by far the most complicated installation of make, because make, also known as GNU Make is a tool for controlling the generation of executables from source files. Based on this, you may find that make is a tool for Linux, not Windows. However, installation on Windows is possible, but somewhat more complex.
Using Chocolatey (Recommended)
This is by far the best way to install make on Windows. Chocolatey is a package manager for Windows that just happens to include make. Installation is fairly simple.

Install Chocolatey

Enter this in PowerShell, or in the PowerShell window in VS Code (this installs Chocolatey):
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

Verify the installation with:
choco -?


Install make via Chocolatey

choco install make

Directly
Another option is to directly install Make for Windows, from GnuWin32. This option is slightly less favorable, and I myself have not tried it.

Install Make for Windows

Go to the GnuWin Make for Windows SourceForge page, in order to install the setup executable. Next, use the setup file to complete installation.
or, run this in PowerShell:
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain

Using WSL
WSL, or Windows Subsystem for Linux is another option. However, this will not actually install make on your machine. It will actually create a virtual Linux machine in your machine, where you can install or use make. This option is probably the least favorable, as you must keep your code inside the virtual machine in order to use it.

Install WSL

Inside PowerSell, install WSL with:
wsl --install

or, to select a distribution manually:
wsl --install -d <distribution>


Install make

Inside the virtual machine, you can install make like normal:
sudo apt install make

Using MinGW
MinGW is one of the best options currently. However, it appears to be no longer maintained.

Install MinGW

Download the MinGW source code here. Select the win32 zip file that matches your device specifications. Then, extract the zip file. The executable files should be in the bin subdirectory.
On Linux
Using apt

Install make

sudo apt install make

Using yum
sudo yum install make

From source
Yes, make uses make for installation. First, use wget to get the compressed source files:
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.bz2

Next, extract the source files:
tar xfj make-3.81.tar.bz2

Next, configure, and install with make:
./configure
make
sudo make install

On Mac
Easy.
brew install make

